# Python list manipulation

Tags: python, list

I've got a python list

```
alist = [ [0, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8,13]], [ [3, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8,999] ]
```

I need the result is

```
alist = [[0,4,8,13], [3, 4, 8, 999]]
```

It means first two and last two numbers in each alist element.

I need a fast way to do this as the list could be huge.

Comment: What bizarre data structure are you modelling?

Comment: I'll bet this is homework.  Only they left off the [Homework] tag.  It's easier to ask here than to think.

Answer (score 12):

```
[x[0][:2] + x[-1][-2:] for x in alist]
```

Answer (score 1):

The object is actually a tuple, rather than a list. This can trip you up if you're expecting it to be mutable and it's hard to read. Consider using the continuation character \ for long lines:

```
alist = [ [0, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8,13]], [ [3, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 999] ]
```

is clearer as

```
alist = [ [0, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8,13]], \
        [ [3, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 999] ]
```

which also helps you spot the double bracket that makes this a tuple. For a list:

```
alist = [ [0, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8,13], \
        [ [3, 4, 5, 5], [2, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 999] ]]
```

If list comprehension as suggested in Javier's answer doesn't meet your speed requirement, consider a numpy array.